# shopify-buy SDK cant checkout or add items to cart anymore

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

[image]

Recently all my Shopify apps have stopped working due to this error. I can still pull data from the api (photos, titles, etc) but I can no longer add items to my cart or check out. this error isn't just happening on my current build but previous builds too. I think I might have made too many requests due to refreshing pages and have been banned from the API temporarily (I've had this happen with another API before). but it's now been 2 days and still no fix.

I'm pretty confident there's nothing wrong with my code because it's happening to other websites that were working before & haven't been touched for a while.

package used: "shopify-buy": "^2.11.0"

Thanks,

Mitchell D

Comment: can you show the API call?

Answer (score 0):

turns out this error occurred because I was in PAUSE AND BUILD mode. so I must be on a plan to add items to the cart using the API? they must have made this change recently